# Appears Black screen with courser on select Entire screen Option in Screen Capturing

Tags: webrtc, screensharing

Appears Black screen with courser on select Entire screen Option in Screen Capturing.I am using this extension it chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capturing/ajhifddimkapgcifgcodmmfdlknahffk

[image: here the first option is entire screen]

[image: as i click entire screen option as you can see in image 1 it'll look lie this]

it must show the whole screen.

please help me out here or is there alternate to share a whole screen for free...

Comment: can you give some more details, like are you checking an online demo, what extensions/ plugins have you installed in your chrome, and if this run from your server, is it in `http` . `https` , and finally if sharing only tabs/window is working?

Comment: 1. Installed screen sharing extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capturing/ajhifddimkapgcifgcodmmfdlknahffk
2. Opened URL - https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/
3. Typed the name in the field and clicked on "share your screen"
4. Observed the screen able to share
Note: when you share the screen a pop up appears please select the first screen with the name "Entire screen" that is not working

Comment: just checked, I am not getting any problems sharing entire screen.

Comment: can yo please share me the image after you select entire screen..

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome, I observe it on Windows7 with lastest Chrome.